# Start-AzLogicApp command does not pass parameter values logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am able to start logic app using "Start-AzLogicApp" command, but parameters passed as part of this command are not actually getting passed to Logic APP. instead default values are used.

Code to trigger logic App
$parameters = @{ "StartTime" = $startTime; "EndTime" = $endTime }
Start-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName myres -Name $logicAppName -MyLogicApp $trigger.Name -Parameters $parameters

Logic App parameter Definition
"parameters":
"EndTime": {
"defaultValue": "temp2",
"type": "String"
},
"StartTime": {
"defaultValue": "temp",
"type": "String"
}

Appreciate if anyone can help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bug of `Start-AzLogicApp` command, here is another [post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8659) about this problem for your reference:

[image]

As a workaround, you can trigger the logic app with parameters by this command below:

```
$parameters = '{ 
    "param1": "abc" 
}'

$headers = @{"Content-Type" = "application/json"}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Body $parameters -Headers $headers
```